# SSIS Precedence Constraint That contains Condition didn't work

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, conditional-statements, etl

I have a SSIS Precedence Constraint expression that has condition within itself. Expression is the following:

```
@[User::del]==0  && ( ( MONTH(@[User::LastImportedDate]) <> 12 ? MONTH( 
@[User::LastImportedDate]) :0 ) <  (MONTH( @[$Package::ExtractDateFrom])-1) )
```

I need to replace value of month for last imported Date with `0` when its value is `12` , and then evaluate if that value is less then month from other date.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found a mistake. It is a syntax error, I should put != instead of  <>